# Javascript touchstart not working at all

Tags: javascript

I have tried to make a swipe movement in my code and the touchstart is not getting initialized. I tried searching in stackoverflow for a solution, couln't find any. I am a newbie in using js. Here is the link :

[Sample](http://codepen.io/avec92/pen/pNbvQw)

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
```

```
var box1 = document.querySelector('.nav');
var startx = 0;
var starty = 0;
var dist = 0;
var endx=0;
var endy=0;

box1.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]; 
    startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX);
```

starty = parseInt(touchobj.clientY); 
    }, false);

```
box1.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]; 
    endx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX);
    endy = parseInt(touchobj.clientY);
let dist = endy - starty;
   window.scrollBy(0, dist);
}, false);

box1.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]; 
   endx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX);
    endy = parseInt(touchobj.clientY);
}, false);
```

}, false);

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});

`
Please help. Also, if there are any alternatives to using touch for implementing swipe, do tell. I cannot use jquery for the same, because I have to replicate it in reactjs. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your code work? What is the problem you are having?

Comment: If you are using PC for testing, Do you have touch emulation enabled in chrome/whatever browser you are using?

Comment: personally recommend http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/index.html touchSwipe for its events, not sure how it goes connecting to react though

Comment: @MartinGottweis Hi, no my code is not working. Given, many browsers are now not allowing touchstart to be initialized, my hands are tied. I am new in this field and am at no wits to see what to do. The problem is that the swipe is not happening. Please click on the word Sample. It will take you to my pen code.
Thanks.

Comment: @VladimirM Yes, I have emulation enabled in the browser(chrome) I am using.

Comment: @Apoorva. that is strage, cause when I loaded your example and added console.log to the "touchstart" handler, I was able to see that in device mode the events were triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've taken look at your code in more details.

1) Providing that your browser is in correct mode, all the events should be triggering. You can check it easily by adding a console log to the corresponding handler.

```
    box1.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        console.log("event start")
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]; 
        startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX); 
        starty = parseInt(touchobj.clientY); 
        console.log("event start done", startx,starty)
    }, false);
```

You should see both entries on the log:

> event start
>
> event start done 95 51

2) Now what is not working in your code is the following line in you touchmove handler:

```
window.scrollBy(0, dist);
```

You window is not overflowing with the content, so there is nothing to scroll to. Your '.nav' block, content of which is wider then the screen, is styled to hide the overflow, and its width:100% only sizes it to the window width, but any overflowing content is still hidden.

At this point I can only guess what was the intended design, but if you change window.scrollBy to the following code:

```
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0];
  el.scrollLeft = el.scrollLeft - dist;
```

You should see some movement in the menu, if events are triggering. In this code I am applying the scroll offset directly to the .nav element, that has hosts the wide content.

3) I don't use reactjs so I cannot recommend any library in particular. But in general, implementing swipe yourself is something you typically want to avoid. I am sure googling for "reactjs swipe" will produce some hits to explore.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir M I'll try this. Also, I already had tried alert box instead of console.log before posting this question and it just wasn't working. That's why I wanted to know the why's of things. I'll try your solution and see how things go.

Comment: Hurrah! There is some movement there. Will work things smoother from there. Thanks again. You are a life saver man!